# Is this a saying? "I am here to [show/tell/...] you ..."

Tags: idioms, phrase-meaning

I am not a native English speaker, but I translate English texts into my native language, Danish.

I sometimes come across phrases like "Many believe that (x) but I am here to show you that (y)."

I sense that "I am here to ..." is not so much about where the person is located, but more that they have a point to make about something. Could this be true? If so, what might be a common equivalent way of saying it? Because, literally translated, it does not carry the same meaning in Danish of making a point - but perhaps an equivalent, alternate way of saying it would.

Comment: Yes, this  meaning can be found in a dictionary, under *here*.  I think you could treat it the same as "but I am telling you" or "but I will show you".

Comment: Or even "but I take it upon myself to to tell/show you".

Comment: Thanks for the dictionary tip. I had looked up idioms with 'here', but a closer look at 'here' at thefreedictionary.com revealed this: 2. at hand, present, available, in attendance: "I'm here to help you."

Comment: But I’d like to tell/show you...

Comment: @Jim - That's exactly what I translated it into initially. :) Thanks for the validation. I guess 'be here to ... you' not really an idom, is it? Just normal language.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Indeed. Or even ***...but luckily**, there's someone here [ specifically, **me**] to set you straight about that common misconception.*

Comment: I’d call it more of a ***Hollywood cliche*** than an actual saying.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: *You* might think so, but I am here to gainsay that perception. :)

Comment: "But I am here to show you that" also simplifies closely to "but in truth," or even "however."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I'm here to tell you that ..." is a fairly common idiom in the US (dunno about the UK), meaning that I'm about to convey to you some "facts" that I feel you need to understand.

I suspect it may, in the past, have had a neutral tone, but it has come to imply that you're about to be lectured about some topic you'd just as soon not hear about.

("I'm hear to show you ..." would not carry the same idiomatic meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

Now, you are kind of correct. At least "I am to ..." is idiomatic (cp ["is to" or "is how to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177416/is-to-or-is-how-to) or [the modal verb Be to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477988/the-modal-verb-be-to), etc) as are *have to, ought to*; Very peculiar and *not* directly comparable to modals like *like*.

More over, to split the difference, *here* alters the meaning significantly.

For translation it might be easier to work with come: "I come by to tell you" which must originally have been subjunctive "came", still visible in "become", "I wish I became ...", but undesrstood as past tense "I have come", and consequently rectified to present tense "I am here", because the process of arrival is largely irrelevant.

That is a good guess, because German *ich komme um euch zu holen* is similarly formulaic. The subjunctive in this word is indistinguishable from the present tense, althoigh the subjunctive is often visible from vowel alternation.

*come* derives from a root "to step", that might play a role for the French simple future for example, though that one is not quite clear. In that sense the phrase can be understood as "procede to", "want to" or just "will" (again, cp French *je vais* "I am going to ...", and *je veut* "I want to"; as well as German *Ich will dir mal was sagen* "I will to tell you something").

Comparing my mother tongue once more, something similator to *here* is used in German to translate the present progressive, "Ich bin *gerade* baden" (*I am bathin', right now).

So, in sum, it's formulaic and you would be well advised to seek a similarly epic expression from Danish.

But that's not an idiomatic saying, no. I don't think that's what *saying* means (cp *saga*, Ger *Sage*). It's an idiomatic phrase, sure.

PS: since someone mentioned *the Doctor is here*, I want to point out English *hoar*, or rather Ger *hehr*, from a root "grey, old, noble". But since this is not obviously attested in context of this phrase, and so would have to be pre-historic, if related all, I would only consider it for translation if archaising the language on purpose. I mean it makes sense, I am proud to tell you that, old, qualified and thus proud. Except I'm not all that qualified, only old.

Answer (score -1):

Clarification was found at https://www.thefreedictionary.com/here
A text search for 'here to' revealed a useful definition:

at hand, present, available, in attendance: *I'm here to help you*.

Thanks to michael.hor257k for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Even this needs care. "I'm here to help, Doug" usually means "I'll be rapidly available if you need me; just call." // With stress,  "I'm _here_ to help, Doug" means that helping is my job / mission. // But "Many believe in General Evolution, but I'm here to tell you that ..." (in a stentorian voice) means that you're on a crusade. Rightly or wrongly. You're stepping up to the plate. Perhaps grandstanding.

Answer (score -2):

In this case "i am here" does refer primary to the location, cardinal and temporal.

The most basic expression that this comes from is something like "Don't worry, he is a doctor, he is here to help you" In this case you are saying that the doctor is in this location, and he is going to do something positive.

I think this specific phrase is popular is infomercials. Very often they would have an excited host telling the audience "you think you have to scrub your dishes for 30 minutes to get them clean, but i am here to tell you that there is new magic soap". In this case the host is using a similar expression because he wants to come off as a friend of the audience, someone to help them, not sell them a product.

This expression has become a sort of joke, so is now used by someone trying to give you facts to change your life.

Comment: No,  it refers to the **role**, not the location.

Comment: @michael.hor257k could you explain that more? As in most cases like this, i have repeated the phrase to myself in Russian and there is no colloquialism that disappears through translation

Comment: See definition 1.3 and its example sentences [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/here). For even better illustration, consider: *"We're not here to do your homework for you."* Clearly, this has nothing to do with location.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have a hard time understanding why people think that a metaphorical place like a website is not a location. You "go" to websites, you "leave" websites. There is no usage in English for a location you can't apply to a website.

Comment: It has nothing to do with location, metaphorical or real.

Comment: Andrey, d'you accept it's possible michael.hor257k is correct? 

When repeating the phrase in Russian, why look at colloquialisms that *disappear* through translation? Is it not more logical to look at what *appears*?

Can you simply accept that "I am here to…" is not literal?

Either way, can you accept that "I am here to…" does mean exactly the same as "I want to", the only difference being style?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin not sure what you mean with the first part. Let's say the sentence was "I am on fire" meaning "I am in the zone". If you say it in Russian "я горю" the meaning is imitatively gone. This is something I can't explain to someone who is not truly bilingual. But it'a then easy to understand that being "on fire" is not a universal concept. On the other hand this construct works in Russian, so I am assuming it will also work in Danish